# AppCompatSpinner MODE_DIALOG программно

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

Пытаюсь создать AppCompatSpinner программно. Но как его программно сделать MODE_DIALOG?
В обычном Spinner получается:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DIALOG);
```

Но в классе AppCompatSpinner переменная MODE_DIALOG объявлена private и написание следующей строки выдаст ошибку:

```
AppCompatSpinner spinner = new AppCompatSpinner(this, AppCompatSpinner.MODE_DIALOG);
```

В описании конструктора класса, самое интересное, написано, что так можно делать. А фактически на private переменную сослаться нельзя.

Comment: может быть использовать `Spinner.MODE_DIALOG` и во втором случае? AppCompatSpinner по идее должен наследоваться от Spinner (проверять мне лень)

Comment: Я тоже так думал, но не работает. Какие варианты только не пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите следующий код:

```
AppCompatSpinner spinner = new AppCompatSpinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DIALOG);
```

Так можно, потому что `AppCompatSpinner` наследуется от класса `Spinner`.

Надеюсь вам помог ответ!

Comment: Так не работает, хотя и компилирует без ошибок. AppCompatSpinner почему-то не отрабатывает переменную из Spinner и остаётся в значении по умолчанию.